# Rails 3.2: marked_for_destruction objects not being verified in validates_length_of. Is that right?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I have a model Purchase with:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :purchase_items, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :purchase_items, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
    validates_length_of :purchase_items, minimum: 1
end
```

And PurchaseItem with:

```
class PurchaseItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :purchase
end
```

Say I have a purchase with only one item. If I mark the item for destruction by doing:

```
purchase.purchase_items.first.mark_for_destruction
purchase.save!
```

The purchase is saved fine, leaving it without any referenced items in the DB.

Inspecting the validate_each method inside ActiveModel::Validations::LengthValidator, we can see that it does not verify if the value being validated has objects marked for destruction.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/length.rb

Is that the normal behavior or it is in fact an issue? If it is normal, what is the correct way to validate the length of a relation along with marked_for_destruction objects?

(without custom validators of course...)

Comment: [This pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9917) seems to imply the validations don't take `mark_for_destruction` into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only choice is to write a custom validator.

This is an open bug, and there is a PR to fix it, but they've just kinda been sitting there for months:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7247

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9917